# Using MYSQLDUMP to backup automatically a DB server

Tags: linux, backup, mysql

I'm using the following in crontab:

```
36 22 * * * root mysqldump -u CENSORED -p CENSORED server | gzip > /home/samp/samp03/scriptfiles/sql-backup/server_backup_`date + \%d-\%m-\%y`.sql
```

but I'm getting the following error in mail (I want to keep the separators [-]):

> date: extra operand `%d-%m-%y'

Comment: Suggest using [`mysql_config_editor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) so you can set-up a cron job without including the login and password.

Comment: I'd rather use it this way, how can I keep the separators and make it work?

Comment: There should not be a space after the `+` in the `date` command.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the `+` and the format specification in the invocation of `date`:

```
date +'\%d-\%m-\%y'
```

When you put a space after the `+`, `date` gets the two arguments `+` and `'\%d-\%m-\%y'`.

Since you're using GNU `date`, which doesn't expect any other command line arguments after a format specification, you get the error message "extra operand" for the string `'\%d-\%m-\%y'`.